# KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started

Tags: testing, kotlin, koin

Using koin-2.0.1 for Android testing and unable to test all 3 test together though each test passes separately.

```
class NumberFormatterUtilImplTest : KoinTest {

    private val numberFormatterUtil: NumberFormatterUtilImpl by inject()

    @Before
    fun setUp() {
        startKoin { modules(utilsModule) }
    }

    @Test
    fun `does formatter returns two digit faction if supplied one digit value`() {
        val result = numberFormatterUtil.getAdjustedCurrencyRate(18.0)
        Assert.assertEquals(result, 18.00, 1.0)
    }

    @Test
    fun `does formatter returns two digit faction if supplied multiple digits value`() {
        val result = numberFormatterUtil.getAdjustedCurrencyRate(18.12343)
        Assert.assertEquals(result, 18.12, 1.0)
    }

    @Test
    fun `does formatter returns rounded two digit faction if supplied multiple digits value`() {
        val result = numberFormatterUtil.getAdjustedCurrencyRate(18.12876)
        Assert.assertEquals(result, 18.13, 1.0)
    }
}
```

running class level testing resulting below:

```
org.koin.core.error.KoinAppAlreadyStartedException: A Koin Application has already been started
```

any input would be helpful, thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

As an alternative to the `@After` approach, you can also use `AutoCloseKoinTest`. [As described in the docs](https://insert-koin.io/docs/2.0/documentation/api/koin-test/org.koin.test/-auto-close-koin-test/index.html):

> Extended Koin Test - embed autoclose @after method to close Koin after every test

Instead of extending `KoinTest`, you can extend `AutoCloseKoinTest` and it will do the after test for you.

Comment: Link does not work. tried both @After and AutoCloseKoinTest and none of the solutions worked. Keep getting the same error

Comment: For JUnit 5: https://doc.insert-koin.io/#/koin-test/testing?id=testing-with-junit5

Comment: link to docs is broken :(

Answer (score 31):

A common practice is to pair `@Before` setup with `@After` cleanup. You can call `stopKoin()` there so the next call to `startKoin()` works again:

```
@After
fun tearDown() {
    stopKoin()
}
```

Comment: Alternately, `@BeforeClass`/`@AfterClass`.

Comment: Extending AutoCloseKoinTest is a more straightforward and concise approach as you do not need to manually write an @After setup to stop koin

Comment: didn't work for me, had to do 
 ``if (KoinContextHandler.getOrNull() == null) {
            startKoin...``

Comment: @hmac Good Idea. In Version 3.1.6 works `GlobalContext.getOrNull()` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Call stopKoin() on @Before and @After method like below:

```
import com.my.example.appModule
import android.os.Build
import androidx.test.core.app.ApplicationProvider
import org.junit.Before
import org.junit.Test
import org.junit.runner.RunWith
import org.koin.android.ext.koin.androidContext
import org.koin.core.context.startKoin
import org.koin.core.context.stopKoin
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config
import java.util.*

@Config(sdk = [Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP])
@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner::class)
class SomeRepositoryTest: KoinTest {

    // Return Completable of RxJava
    private val repository: SomeRepository by inject()

    @Before
    fun before() {
        stopKoin() // to remove 'A Koin Application has already been started'
        startKoin {
            androidContext(ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext())
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }

    @After
    fun after() {
        stopKoin()
    }

    @Test
    fun testSomething() {

        repository.insert("data").blockingAwait()

        assert(true)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way to resolve this it override `onTerminate` in your application where you start Koin

```
override fun onTerminate() {
    super.onTerminate()     
    stopKoin()              
}
```

With this way you will not have to use `AutoCloseKoinTest` or close it in every class test in the `@after`

Answer (score 1):

Implementing the abstract AutoCloseKoinTest class will automatically stop Koin after each test.

Here's an example with Robolectric:

```
@RunWith(RoboelectricTestRunner::class)
class MyTest : AutoCloseKoinTest() {
   private val appContext = ApplicationProvider.getApplicationContext<APPNAME>()

   @Before
   fun setup() {
      // use appContext as needed
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For the ktor users:

If you're facing this issue while using the testApplication function from ktor.

Be aware that the local test application also starts the koin "application".
At least if you are following the official koin ktor getting started setup.

The most straight forward solution, that I came up with so far is wrapping the koin startup in your *Application.module()* into a condition which checks if there is already a koin instance:

```
fun Application.module() {

if (GlobalContext.getOrNull() == null) {
    install(Koin) {
        slf4jLogger()
        modules(appModule)
    }
}

configureRouting()
configureSerialization()
...
```

Of course you then make sure that you properly start and stop koin in your tests.

For examples, you can look at the other posts here.

Or just use:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    if (GlobalContext.getOrNull() == null) {
        startKoin {
            modules(appModule)
        }
    }
}

@After
fun tearDown() {
    stopKoin()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I got this issue with `startKoin` I switched to `loadKoinModules` so my test turned to something like:

```
@Before
fun setUp() {
    loadKoinModules(modules)
}
@After
fun tearDown() {
    unloadKoinModules(modules)
}
```