# Setting up a test with Koin in ktor

Tags: testing, ktor, koin

How would you go about setting up a test with koin in ktor. So what i mean is that i wanna test my ktor application so my routes for example... This i wanna do with the help of dependency injection with the help of Koin. When i try to start koin and setup my test modules i get the error that says A koin application is already running. but i seriously have no clue what to do against it? my testclass looks like the code bellow. I have watched a tutorial from philip lackner where he sets up a test with the help of withApplication and handlerequest bhut nothing is working and im about to go insane on this crazy testing. I mean when the testing is actually harder then creating the server itself i start wondering why to do it..... is there an easier way to setup a test in Ktor with koin and a fake repository?

```
package com.PapperSeller.routes

import com.PapperSeller.di.testModule
import com.PapperSeller.repository.user.FakeUserRepository
import io.ktor.server.application.*
import io.ktor.server.routing.*
import io.ktor.server.testing.*
import org.koin.core.context.GlobalContext.startKoin
import org.koin.dsl.module
import org.koin.test.KoinTest
import org.koin.test.inject
import kotlin.test.BeforeTest
import kotlin.test.Test


internal class UserRoutesKtTest : KoinTest{
    private val testUserRepository by inject<FakeUserRepository>()

    @BeforeTest
    fun setup(){
        startKoin{
            modules(module { single { testModule } })
        }
    }


    @Test
    fun `Create user, no body attached, responds with BadRequest`() = testApplication{
       application {

       }


    }

}
```

Comment: Please check this question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57038848/koinappalreadystartedexception-a-koin-application-has-already-been-started

Comment: This does not work it still gives the same error

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem recently,  i solved this by turning off my development mode.
Place this block of code inside testApplication{} block and try again

```kotlin
    environment {
       developmentMode = false
    }
```

and also add afterTest block for stoping koin

```kotlin
    @AfterTest
    fun tearDown() {
       stopKoin()
    }
```